# Plugin installation with ES 5.0 Alpha-3

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I have recently tried to install Elasticsearch 5.0 Alpha-3

However, when I try to install plugins, it keeps giving me error, stopping me from installing, for example

```
PS C:\ELK\elasticsearch> bin/elasticsearch-plugin install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/3.1.2
-> Downloading elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/3.1.2
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/3
.1.2
```

Is this a bug or common error?

Comment: Why not simply `bin/elasticsearch-plugin install mapper-attachments`like stated in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/mapper-attachments.html)?

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install mapper-attachments
```

Note that this plugin is deprecated and that you'd better use ingest-attachment plugin instead.